# How to find the revisions in a merge?

Tags: svn

Let's say I have a trunk and a branch.

In the branch Billy-Bob has merged a change from the trunk into the branch with the comment "Merged changes for release". How would I find out what revisions were merged over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the option --use-merge-history for 'svn log'. This will give you the revisions of the file on the local branch, as well as any merged revisions. Add -v for the verbose output that will show the path/url the revision took place on.

```
svn log [-g|--use-merge-history] [-v|--verbose] <path|url>
```

Answer (score 1):

If Billy-Bob has done things properly, then SVN stores the merged revisions in a special property, "svn:mergeinfo". The command `svn mergeinfo --show-revs merged trunk_url branch_url` will show that information to you. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.mergeinfo.html for details.

If you use TortoiseSVN, you can check the "show merged revisions" box in the "Show Log" dialog, to see all the merged revisions.

If Billy-Bob is ignorant about how to merge properly, and neglected to commit the svn:mergeinfo changes, then you're out of luck.